# Let F be a distribution function. Prove that X is a RV

Tags: probability, self-study

Let $F$ be a distribution function on $(\Omega,\, \mathfrak{F},\, P)=\left((0,1),\ \mathfrak{B}(0,1),\ \lambda\right)$ where $\lambda$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

Define  $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ by $X(\omega) = \sup(y \in \mathbb{R}: F(y) < \omega)$.

1 Show that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, (\omega: X(\omega) \leq x) = (\omega: \omega \leq F(x))$

2 Show that $X$ is a RV in $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$ and that $F_X = F$.

My attempt:

LHS = $(\omega: X(\omega) \leq x)$

= $(\omega: X(\omega) \in (-\infty, x])$

= $(\omega: \sup(y \in \mathbb{R}: F(y) < \omega) \in (\infty, x])$

RHS = $(\omega: \omega \leq F(x))$

= $(\omega: \omega \in (-\infty, F(x)])$

= $(\omega: \omega \in (-\infty, P(X^{-1}( \ (-\infty,x] \ ))))$

= $(\omega: \omega \in (-\infty, P(LHS)))$

I'm stuck. Help please? :(

Cross posted : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888054/let-f-be-a-distribution-function-prove-that-x-is-a-rv

Comment: Hints: For (1), what do you understand "$\sup$" to mean?  For (2), begin with a *definition*: what kind of mathematical object is a random variable ("RV") and what properties must it have?

Comment: @whuber Are you referring to question 2 or 1? If 2, $X^{-1}(B) \in \mathfrak{F} \forall B \in \mathfrak{B}$. Hmmm...does the 1st part of 2 follow from the fact that $X^{-1}(\sup(y \in \mathbb{R}: F(y) < \omega)) \in \mathfrak{F}$ and the fact that $\sup(y \in \mathbb{R}: F(y) < \omega) \in \mathfrak{B}$? No idea for 2nd part of 2. If 1, X^{-1}(B) \in \mathfrak{F} \forall B \in \mathfrak{B}$. What may I ask is the relevance?